# Dell PowerConnect 2848 Link Aggregation

Tags: dell, dell-powerconnect

I saw some similar posts but nothing like my problem. Thing is, I have a R210II server with NIC Teaming enabled, so 2 nics look like 1. So far so good, both ports of the teammed nics are connected to my PowerConnect 2848. Theres only one base vlan for the whole network.

So every time I enable the LAG for the 2 ports where the server is connected I lose my connection to the server, at this moment I have a teammed server but one port having more traffic than another.

Documentation of the switch is lame and Dell forum don't reply to any questions.

Can anyone please help? Why in the name of Poseidon I can't keep my connection up since i'm following every instruction of the manufacturer?

/Edit - Thanks a lot MFINNI, it was very helpful.

Comment: What OS is on the R210II?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you configuring the NIC teaming? Are you using the Broadcom config tool for this? Depending on the mode you choose, you don't need to configure anything on the switch at all, and if you do, you'll break the team. If the team that you've made on the server is working, you're done, you've accomplished your goal.

The two NICs are not going to have the exact same number of bits passing through them.

/Edit - Understand, you've got to read the docs. In this case, the Broadcom docs.
http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/management_applications.php

- Smart Load Balancing and Failover... No switch configuration (such as trunk or link aggregation) is required.
- Link Aggregation and Generic Trunking: these operating modes increase throughput in both directions and conform to the IEEE 802.3ad (LACP) specification.

You're doing the first one, so don't configure the switch for anything. If you want/need to use some form of LAG, set up the team that way and then configure the switch to match.

Comment: Yes it is configured using BCSAS , chose for Load Balancing Fail Over. But the LAG on the switch is suposed to give me more bandwidth. So as you said, am I breaking the team?

Comment: Edited my answer.